# How to implement a callback in a callback in a callback combined with setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have three functions which need to be executed in the correct order. They need to be prepared using the callbacks.

```
function stepOne(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Step 1 completed")
  },1000)
}

function stepTwo(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Step 2 completed")
  },500)
}

function stepThree(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Step 3 completed")
  },500)
}
```

The functions should have callbacks as arguments and execute them in the setTimeout. But when I implement this approach and make

```
function stepOne(callback){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Step 1 completed")
      callback()
  },1000)
}

function stepTwo(callback){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Step 2 completed")
      callback()
  },500)
}

stepOne(stepTwo(stepThree))
```

I get an error that the callback is not a function. What do I do wrong in the process?

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking `stepTwo(stepThree)` instead of actually passing in the function `stepTwo`, so you're technically passing `void` to it as an argument since it's not returning anything.  In other words you're actually calling step 2 and not passing the function itself.

```
const stepOne = (callback) => {
  ...
  setTimeout(callback, 1000)
}

const stepTwo = (callback) => {
  ...
  setTimeout(callback), 1000)
}

const stepThree = () => {
  ...
  // execute step three
}

stepOne(() => stepTwo(stepThree)),
```

Instead you can create an anonymous function and let that invoke the next step with an argument.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for the clarification, everything works well now.

Answer (score 0):

You’d need to have stepTwo return a function:

```
function stepOne(callback){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Step 1 completed")
      callback()
  },1000)
}

function stepTwo(callback){
  return function() { 
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("Step 2 completed")
        callback()
    },500),
  }
}

stepOne(stepTwo(stepThree))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one neat trick called being generic you could use.

```
const execCallBackChain = (...chain) => {
    chain.length > 0 && setTimeout(() => {
         const cb = chain.shift();
         typeof cb === 'function' && cb();
         execCallBackChain(...chain);
    }, 1000); 
}
```

then call for any number of functions you want in series fashion,

```
execCallBackChain(func1, func2, func3, .... , funcN);
```